# Is there an R function for combining graph for decomposition of time series graph?

Tags: r

I used `par()` to combine the graph, but it is not working

```
d1=decompose(abuja)
d2=decompose(ilorin)
d3=decompose(jos)
d4=decompose(lafia)
d5=decompose(lokoja)
d6=decompose(makurdi)
d7=decompose(minna)

par(mfrow=c(7,1))
plot(d1)
plot(d2)
plot(d3)
plot(d4)
plot(d5)
plot(d6)
plot(d7)
```

After doing this, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! `par()` won't work because `plot.decomposed.ts()` (which you implicitly call when calling `plot()`) isn't designed to work that way. The most straightforward alternative is to use `autoplot()` from the `forecast` package to generate decomposition plots and combine them using patchwork.

Here is an example.

```
m1 = decompose(co2)
m2 = decompose(AirPassengers)
m3 = decompose(UKgas)
p1 = autoplot(m1)
p2 = autoplot(m2)
p3 = autoplot(m3)
p1 / p2 / p3
```

The last line, `p1 / p2 / p3`, tells R to stack them vertically. If you want to stack them horizontally, use `p1 + p2 + p3`. If you're being feisty, you can also try `(p1 + p2)/p3` to stack the first two horizontally and the last one beneath it.

[image: stacked vertically]
[image: stacked horizontally]
[image: stacked crazily]